# Eclipse with maven workspace dependency - packaged war contain folder instead of jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-war-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SR2 with m2e.
I have a web project that depends on a jar.

When I use "Run as -> Maven Build..." with goal package and "Check Workspace artifacts" is checked, then the lib folder in the target contains a folder with the name of the dependency jar, instead of the jar itself. The packaged war also contains a folder instead of a jar. However, when deploying to tomcat with m2e, the jar is deployed correctly.

I use maven-war-plugin version 2.4.

This is my WAR pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.modelity.loans</groupId>
    <artifactId>loans-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>loans-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.modelity.loans</groupId>
        <artifactId>loans-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And this is the artifact coordinates of the dependency jar:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.modelity.loans</groupId>
    <artifactId>loans-lib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>loans-core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I've looked at the debug output of the maven package goal. When the war plugin is processing the jars, it says

```
[DEBUG] Processing: loans-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

without indicating the jar has been copied.
Later on in the log I see:

```
adding directory WEB-INF/lib/loans-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/
```

I've tried both embedded maven (3.0.4) and external maven (3.0.5).
My colleague uses kepler SR1, and experience the same problem.

I think I've covered it all. Would be happy for some advise, couldn't find any reported bug about it.

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the jar as its own maven-controlled artifact:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=my.jar -DgroupId=com.mycorp -DartifactId=my-jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And then define it as a maven dependency for your war

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't rely on resolving workspace dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

now we have 2018 and the problem still exists in eclipse v2018-09. Maven Dependencies which exist in the workspace are exploded into WEB-INF/lib folder.

Found this old bug report https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-22157 regarding this behaviour.

Solution is to disable "dependency resolution from workspace projects" in maven project settings.

[image: screenshot of project properties]

regards,
Markus